# I get empty string when i use entry in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to add a file path to my application using an entry, but every time the entry returns an empty string

```
def command1(event):
    if entry1.get() == 'localhost' and entry2.get() == 'amine' and   entry3.get()=='aze123qsd' and entry4.get()=='GTFS':
    top = Toplevel()
    top.title("Add a file")
    top.geometry("600x300")
    text=Label(top ,text="Add the file path")
    text.place(relx=0.3 ,rely=0.3)
    entry=Entry(top)
    entry.place(relx=0.5 ,rely=0.3)
    paths=entry.get()
    entry.bind('<Return>', commnad3)
    button1 = Button(top, text="show the last window")
    button1.place(relx=0.55 ,rely=0.7)
    button2 =Button(top ,text="Use old data", command=old)
    button2.place(relx=0.3 ,rely=0.7)
```

Comment: `entry.get()` is being ran at immediately after `entry` is defined and not later after you have put something in entry. You need to put `entry.get()` into a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is due to creating `entry` at the same time you are performing `get()` on that entry. All you will have at that moment is an empty entry field.

You need to grab that entry information after something has been put into it.

Take this example and let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()


def print_entry(e):
    print(e.get())


def command1():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    entry = tk.Entry(top)
    entry.pack()
    tk.Button(top, text="Print Entry", command=lambda: print_entry(entry)).pack()


tk.Button(root, text="TOPLEVEL", command=command1).pack()

root.mainloop()
```